How to save image obtained from the Internet to Google Drive
I have the links to the images saved in column A and use the image() function to show the images in column B. Is there a way to save all the images in google drive please?
PS After I try to use the suggested appscript, I got an error message on this line:
var image=UrlFetchApp.fetch(imgurl).getBlob().getAs('image/png').setName(name)

The error message is:
Error   
Exception: Attribute provided with no value: url
uploadFiles @ Code.gs:45

The entire function is:
function uploadFiles() {
  var ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var sh=ss.getActiveSheet();
  var rg=sh.getDataRange();
  var vA=rg.getValues();
  for(var i=0;i<vA.length;i++) {
    var imgurl=vA[i][0];//Column A for url
    var name=vA[i][2];//Column C for filename
    var image=UrlFetchApp.fetch(imgurl).getBlob().getAs('image/png').setName(name);
    var folder=DriveApp.getFolderById('1fINtohfuEjUdYeNrSxRlailhNHVElF24');
    var file=DriveApp.createFile(image);
    Drive.Files.update({"parents": [{"id": folder.getId()}]}, file.getId());
  }
}


How were you hoping to do that?  You can write a Google Apps Script program to do that, or you can use the Google API from another application.
